# what could cause a rails scope to throw a NoMethodError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

What could cause a rails app to have a no method error when using a scope?

I have a basic user class that has cats and dogs. I will need to combine the queries and sort them by created date. Eventually the individual queries will be more complex.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :dogs
        has_many :cats

       scope :pets, joins(:dogs).joins(:cats).order("created_at desc")
```

In view

```
    <%= render @user.pets%>
```

Is causing an no method error

```
    undefined method `pets' for #<User:0x00000106370cb0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes only define class methods on the ActiveRecord model. The proper way to call this would be on the User model directly. `User.pets` as opposed to an instance of User `@user.pets`.

What you could do is create a method to be called on a User instance.

```
   def pets
     User.joins(:dogs).joins(:cats).order("created_at desc")
   end
```

And thus, `@user.pets` is allowed.